# Can you get minetest 5.0.0 on the raspberry pi 3 b +?

Tags: pi-3

I use minetest 4.17 on the raspberry pi and all the games are updateing, I really want to find a way for 5.0 to work on the pi, please help me!!!

Comment: what does this mean and how is it relevant to the question? ... `all the games are updateing`

Comment: have you tried building it from source?

Comment: No Chad G, I have no idea what to do to get it, but if you can help me, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo apt install git g++ make libc6-dev libirrlicht-dev cmake libbz2-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libxxf86vm-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libsqlite3-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libopenal-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev libgmp-dev libjsoncpp-dev`
2. `git clone https://github.com/minetest/minetest`
3. `cd minetest/games`
4. `git clone https://github.com/minetest/minetest_game`
5. `cd ..`
6. `cmake . -DRUN_IN_PLACE=TRUE -DENABLE_GETTEXT=TRUE -DENABLE_CURL=TRUE`

After these commands, disable GUI and do this command:

7. `make -j2`

Comment: Compiling from source works on a Raspi 4 and the game is pretty playable. However the above example could be adapted (for example, to allow for sound). The Readme over at https://github.com/minetest/minetest does a great job listing all the options (and will always be up to date).